# lock range based on cell value

Tags: excel, integer, locking, vba

I am trying to write this VBA so that if cell(U5) = "YES" then range(B5:T5) are locked else range(B5:T5) remains unlocked. Similarly if cell(U6) = "YES" then range(B6:T6) are locked else range(B6:T6) remains unlocked and so on.  Unfortunately my codes are not running and I am unable to find the error! Please find my mistake!

[image: my VBA code]

Comment: please do not post the code in a photo.  We cannot copy paste a photo

Comment: You should unprotect the sheet *before* the loop and protect it back *after* the loop finishes.

Comment: Your nesting is wrong with your if statements .... the 2nd IF can never be true methinks

Comment: Optimally speaking, you only have to do anything if the values in column U are changed and then only to the cells in B:T on the rows where U has changed. What happens if someone removed (clears/deletes) the Yes/No from column U?

Comment: Subject to @ScottCraner's comment, we also would not be able to see that you are trying to get someone to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

From your narrative, I've gathered that you only have to do anything if the values in column U are changed and then only to the cells in B:T on the rows where U has changed.

There is no indication as to what should happen if the cells in column U are neither Yes or No. I've left an area for you to deal with that if you want to.

You were using `i + 21` in the column number parameter of cells. This means that the first time the loop goes through it is U5. On the second iteration it is now V6; on the third W7, etc. This is not what your narrative states so I followed the narrative's instructions and assumed a simple coding error. This also means that (if you had run through the code previously) you may have inadvertently 'locked' the wrong cells. If that is the case, you might just want to start on a new worksheet and delete the one you had been working on.

The [Worksheet.Protect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) has an optional parameter for `UserInterfaceOnly`. When set to True, the user is restricted by a protected worksheet but no VBA code is similarly protected. This means that you do not have to [.Unprotect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841143.aspx) the worksheet to run your code. I've added a 'helper' sub procedure; run it once and then you do not have to Unprotect and reProtect the worksheet.

If you choose not to use `UserInterfaceOnly` protection, move the .Protect and .Unprotect statements outside the loop so that they are not performed for each row.

[image]